# Sqlite3 connection fails once deployed on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, sqlite, flask, package

I've created a package on my own which contains a sqlite3 database. I use python flask framework for back end programming and I can use my package without any restrictions.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_file = os.path.join(dir_path, 'szs.db')

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = lite.connect(db_file)
        ...
```

But as soon I deploy my flask project on `heroku` which uses my package with the sqlite3 database I get following error:

```
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403525+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403526+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403528+00:00 app[web.1]:     from .concrete import concrete
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403530+00:00 app[web.1]:     from .views import concrete
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403529+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/concrete/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403532+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/concrete/views.py", line 5, in <module>
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403533+00:00 app[web.1]:     from .forms import BendingForce, ShearForce, Profile
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403534+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/concrete/forms.py", line 119, in <module>
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403536+00:00 app[web.1]:     sizes = [(j, j) for j in Database().select_col('IPE', 'size')]
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403537+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/civeng/steel/szs.py", line 38, in select_col
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403538+00:00 app[web.1]:     cur.execute('SELECT '+col+' FROM '+table+'')
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403539+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: IPE
2015-10-11T19:53:35.403546+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 19:53:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2015-10-11T19:53:35.551918+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 19:53:35 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2015-10-11T19:53:35.551994+00:00 app[web.1]: [2015-10-11 19:53:35 +0000] [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2015-10-11T19:53:36.431233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-10-11T19:53:36.409628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2015-10-11T19:53:55.196843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=probus.herokuapp.com request_id=48aa4176-88f8-456f-ac86-bba688e4215f fwd="178.199.176.52" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

What seems to be the matter? Wrong connection to the database file?

Comment: Please note that sqlite3 is not recommended for production systems or Heroku.  When you redeploy / restart your application, or Heroku recycles your application, then you will loose data stored in sqlite3.  If you need a persistent database, I suggest trying Heroku Postgres https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was the package. The database file was not shipped with it. So I had to add the following line to my setup file: `package_data={'civeng/steel': ['szs.db'],}`

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='civeng',
    version='0.2.7',
    description='civil engineering tools',
    url='https://pypi.python.org/pypi/civeng',
    author='author',
    author_email='author@email.com',
    license='GPLv3',
    packages=['civeng', 
                'civeng/concrete', 
                'civeng/concrete/modules',
                'civeng/steel',
                'civeng/steel/modules',],
    package_data={'civeng/steel': ['szs.db'],},
    zip_safe=False)
```